# How do I extend the length of time for an audio synthesizer?

Tags: c#, audio

I created an audio synthesizer using info found at  http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/.

```
private const int SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;
private const short BITS_PER_SAMPLE = 16;
short[] asSoundValues = new short[SAMPLE_RATE]
float fFreq = 440;

for (int iValueCount = 0; iValueCount < SAMPLE_RATE; iValueCount++) 
{
  asSoundValues[iValueCount] = Convert.ToInt16(short.MaxValue *
    Math.Sin(((Math.PI * 2 * fFreq) / SAMPLE_RATE) * iValueCount));
}

byte[] abBinarySoundValues = new byte[SAMPLE_RATE * sizeof(short)];
Buffer.BlockCopy(asSoundValues, 0, abBinarySoundValues, 0,
                   asSoundValues.Length * sizeof(short));
using (MemoryStream msMemoryStream = new MemoryStream()) 
{
  using (BinaryWriter bwBinaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(msMemoryStream)) 
  {
    short sBlockAlign = BITS_PER_SAMPLE / 8;
    int iSubChunkTwoSize = SAMPLE_RATE * sBlockAlign;
    bwBinaryWriter.Write(new[] { 'R', 'I', 'F', 'F' });
    bwBinaryWriter.Write(36 + iSubChunkTwoSize);
    bwBinaryWriter.Write(new[] { 'W', 'A', 'V', 'E', 'f', 'm', 't', ' ' });
    bwBinaryWriter.Write(16);
    bwBinaryWriter.Write((short)1);
    bwBinaryWriter.Write((short)1);
    bwBinaryWriter.Write(SAMPLE_RATE);
    bwBinaryWriter.Write(SAMPLE_RATE * sBlockAlign);
    bwBinaryWriter.Write(sBlockAlign);
    bwBinaryWriter.Write(BITS_PER_SAMPLE);
    bwBinaryWriter.Write(new[] { 'd', 'a', 't', 'a' });
    bwBinaryWriter.Write(iSubChunkTwoSize);
    bwBinaryWriter.Write(abBinarySoundValues);
    msMemoryStream.Position = 0;
    new SoundPlayer(msMemoryStream).Play();
  }
}
```

The sound lasts 1 second. How do I extend that sound to last longer --- such as 5 seconds?

Comment: `short[] asSoundValues = new short[SAMPLE_RATE * numberOfSeconds]`?

Comment: Tried that - length is still 1 second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works (if I didn't make any typos):

```
private const int SAMPLE_RATE = 44100;
private const short BITS_PER_SAMPLE = 16;
short[] asSoundValues = new short[SAMPLE_RATE]
float fFreq = 440;
int iLengthOfTimeInSecs = 5;

for (int iValueCount = 0; iValueCount < SAMPLE_RATE; iValueCount++) 
{
  asSoundValues[iValueCount] = Convert.ToInt16(short.MaxValue *
    Math.Sin(((Math.PI * 2 * fFreq) / SAMPLE_RATE) * iValueCount));
}

int iNumOfShortsIn_asSoundValuesArray = SAMPLE_RATE;
int iNumOfBytesIn_asSoundValuesArray = SAMPLE_RATE * sizeof(short);
int iNumOfBytesIn_abBinarySoundValuesArray = iNumOfBytesIn_asSoundValuesArray *
                                               iLengthOfTimeInSecs;
byte[] abBinarySoundValues = new byte[iNumOfBytesIn_abBinarySoundValuesArray];
for (int ii = 0; ii < iLengthOfTimeInSecs; ii++) 
{
  Buffer.BlockCopy(asSoundValues, 
                    0, 
                    abBinarySoundValues, 
                    iNumOfBytesIn_asSoundValuesArray * ii,
                    iNumOfBytesIn_asSoundValuesArray);
}
using (MemoryStream msMemoryStream = new MemoryStream()) 
{
  using (BinaryWriter bwBinaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(msMemoryStream)) 
  {      
    short sBlockAlign = BITS_PER_SAMPLE / 8;
    int iSubChunkTwoSize = iNumOfShortsIn_asSoundValuesArray * 
                             sBlockAlign * iLengthOfTimeInSecs;
    bwBinaryWriter.Write(new[] { 'R', 'I', 'F', 'F' });
    bwBinaryWriter.Write(36 + iSubChunkTwoSize);
    bwBinaryWriter.Write(new[] { 'W', 'A', 'V', 'E', 'f', 'm', 't', ' ' });
    bwBinaryWriter.Write(16);
    bwBinaryWriter.Write((short)1);
    bwBinaryWriter.Write((short)1);
    bwBinaryWriter.Write(iNumOfShortsIn_asSoundValuesArray);
    bwBinaryWriter.Write(iNumOfShortsIn_asSoundValuesArray * sBlockAlign);
    bwBinaryWriter.Write(sBlockAlign);
    bwBinaryWriter.Write(BITS_PER_SAMPLE);
    bwBinaryWriter.Write(new[] { 'd', 'a', 't', 'a' });
    bwBinaryWriter.Write(iSubChunkTwoSize);
    bwBinaryWriter.Write(abBinarySoundValues);
    msMemoryStream.Position = 0;
    new SoundPlayer(msMemoryStream).Play();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [wave format](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/), `Subchunk2Size` is what ultimately determines the length of a WAV, which helped me figure out all that would have to be changed besides your sample arrays. So, these are all the changes you'll have to make:

```
for (int iValueCount = 0; iValueCount < SAMPLE_RATE * numberOfSeconds; iValueCount++) 
short[] asSoundValues = new short[SAMPLE_RATE * numberOfSeconds]
byte[] abBinarySoundValues = new byte[SAMPLE_RATE * sizeof(short) * numberOfSeconds];
int iSubChunkTwoSize = SAMPLE_RATE * sBlockAlign * numberOfSeconds;
```

Comment: That is close!  A 2 second example:  the abBinarySoundValues first half must be filled with asSoundValues - second half must also filled with asSoundValues.

Comment: @ttom I updated my answer; your for loop also needed a change.